# terraform apply reporting backend configuration error with S3 after terraform init & terraform plan worked successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am running terraform on my Linux instance and I am getting the terrors below.

```
+ /usr/local/bin/terraform workspace new test
enter code here[0m[0m[1m[33mBackend reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".[0m

[33mReason: Initial configuration of the requested backend "s3"
The "backend" is the interface that Terraform uses to store state,
perform operations, etc. If this message is showing up, it means that the
Terraform configuration you're using is using a custom configuration for
the Terraform backend.

Changes to backend configurations require reinitialization. This allows
Terraform to setup the new configuration, copy existing state, etc. This is
only done during "terraform init". Please run that command now then try again.

If the change reason above is incorrect, please verify your configuration
hasn't changed and try again. At this point, no changes to your existing
configuration or state have been made.
[0m
[31mFailed to load backend: Initialization required. Please see the error message above.
```

Here is the Terraform configuration file.

```
provider "aws" {
  # don't touch below here
  access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
  secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
  region     = "us-west-2"
}

# Configure Terraform to store this in S3
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "nom-terraform"
    key    = "apps/onboarding/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-west-2"
  }
}
```

Before running terraform apply, I managed to run `terraform plan` successfully.

Comment: try deleting the ".terraform" folder and re-run terraform init ?

Comment: @keety I am running it on linux environment and can you let me know exactly where to find that .terraform folder?

Comment: Its in whatever directory you are working from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you have added new s3 as backend. 
So terraform requires re-initialization.
Just run `terraform init`, it will add s3 as backend and ask permission to transfer local statefile to s3.

Comment: I tried doing it. It stil the same. terraform init works and apply threw the same error. :(

Comment: same problem here

Comment: Could you please share the error @PedroBezanilla

Comment: @deepak " Backend reinitialization required. Please run "terraform init".
Reason: Initial configuration of the requested backend "s3" "   showing since I started to use a backend config : terraform init \ -backend-config=backend.tfvars

Answer (score 1):

I would first delete any state file and the .terraform folder, many error exist sometimes due to corruption.

Afterwards I would run init and it should run.

I do not believe adding the backend was the issue as it should have tried to merge between the states

Answer (score 0):

You would need to first initialise the provide, that download the provider with the latest version, the output would be something like this :-

```
# terraform init

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins on https://releases.hashicorp.com...
- Downloading plugin for provider "spotinst" (1.1.1)...

The following providers do not have any version constraints in configuration,
so the latest version was installed.

To prevent automatic upgrades to new major versions that may contain breaking
changes, it is recommended to add version = "..." constraints to the
corresponding provider blocks in configuration, with the constraint strings
suggested below.

* provider.aws: version = "~> 1.2"
* provider.cloudflare: version = "~> 0.1"
* provider.spotinst: version = "~> 1.1"

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.`
```