# "Initial configuration of the requested backend" despite having run terraform init -backend=false

Tags: terraform

I have a single terraform file in my terraform repo:

```
# main.tf
terraform {
  backend "remote" {
    hostname = "app.terraform.io"
  }
}
```

and one config file

```
# backend_config.hcl
workspaces { name = "my-workspace" }
organization = "my-favourite-organisation"
```

I want to initialise my repo for local planning, but I don't have access to the real state file:

```sh
$ terraform init -backend-config=backend_config.hcl

Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Required token could not be found
│
│ Run the following command to generate a token for app.terraform.io:
│     terraform login
╵
```

So I initialise without a backend:

```
$ terraform init -backend=false

Initializing provider plugins...

Terraform has been successfully initialized!
```

But now when I try and plan, Terraform complains that the backend needs to be initialised:

```sh
$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Backend initialization required, please run "terraform init"
│
│ Reason: Initial configuration of the requested backend "remote"
```

What can I do to plan locally without access to my remote statefile?

Comment: Looks similar to, but isn't the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/68985429/2071807

Comment: Looks similar to, but isn't the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/50819556/2071807

Comment: You cannot `plan` with no backend initialization. That is for other commands such as `validate`. When you are supplying the backend with the TFCloud workspace and org, the CLI is querying you for authentication. Are you unable to locally authenticate against TF Cloud with a user or team?

Comment: @MattSchuchard, yes we're not allowed to log in to TF Cloud. So am I out of options in terms of locally planning? Can I even check what my resources would create, regardless of the current state of our TF Cloud state file?

Answer (score 0):

To initialize backend in local system.
`$ terraform init`
`$ terraform plan`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).